# What is the difference between ion beam and laser?

Tags: nuclear-physics, laser, fusion, ions, laser-interaction

What is the difference between laser beams and ion beams, especially in inertial confinement fusion?

In inertial fusion, we use lasers as well as ion beams for driving the reaction. What is the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An *ion beam* is a stream of [ionized particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionization), meaning that they are more reactive, either have too many or too few electrons.

A *laser beam* is a stream of photons, of [coherent light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_(physics)).

What both have in common though is the fact that they transport energy (in different ways though).

Comment: thank you very much